# ANDROID_HOME is set but i cannot build app

Tags: android, macos, ionic-framework

I've installed AndroidSDK in mac_osx el capitain.Commands like `android` or `adb` works fine.When i try to build ionic app with `sudo ionic build android` i receive `ANDROID_HOME is not in my path`.What can i do ?

Comment: Try with this path 
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Hybrid_Mobile_App/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
Replace with your PWD

Comment: run command in terminal  "echo $ANDROID_HOME" to check whether ANDROID_HOME  is properly set or not.

Comment: I've tried but no result.android command works but when i want to make build i receive the error.Can be sudo the reason?How i can set env var instead of terminal?

Comment: When i type echo $ANDROID_HOME is not giving me any result .That means is not set

Answer (score 0):

**Instruction 1:** 
After adding your ANDROID_HOME, make sure you do the below:

1. Restart your System or run source ~/.bash_profile
2. Remove Android platform from your project ionic cordova platform rm android or ionic platform rm android
3. Add Android platform ionic cordova platform add android
4. Then ionic cordova run android or ionic run android

**Instruction 2:** 
To set your ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME, follow the below steps:

1. Run command open ~/.bash_profile
2. Paste the below in the file that opens on your Text editor

export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

3. Save  -  "Command S" or "Ctrl S"
4. Then Follow the "Instruction 1:" above

Hope this helps.....